# How much variance is captured by the RFF maps?

Tags: references, machine-learning

The RFF maps [here](http://machinelearning.wustl.edu/mlpapers/paper_files/NIPS2007_833.pdf) are possibly the most used feature maps. I was wondering if there are cases where anyone has theoretically estimated the total variance captured by these maps? Is any simplification or optimization known to happen (in maybe experiments) when the data is coming from some manifold of low dimension?

---

An "empirical" version of this question might be set up like this : Say $X$ is a $d \times n$ matrix of $n$ data vectors in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Now using $D (> d)$ dimensional RFFs one creates from this a matrix $X_{RFF}$ which is $D \times n$ dimensional. But since there are random choices ($D$ vectors $\vec{\omega} \in \mathbb{R}^d$ packed into a single $d\times D$ matrix $\omega$  and $b \in \mathbb{R}^D$) involved in creating the RFF map, $X_{RFF}$ is not a fixed matrix. Now choose some $k < d$ and lets say one computes the sum of the top $k$ eigenvalues of $XX^T$ as well as $X_{RFF} X_{RFF}^T$ (the respective covariance matrices) Lets denote these sums as $\sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i (XX^T )$  and $\sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i (X_{RFF}X_{RFF}^T)$. Now what one wants to know is the expected ``error" i.e $\mathbb{E}_{\omega, \vec{b}}  [\sum_{i=1}^k ( \lambda_i (XX^T ) - \lambda_i (X_{RFF}X_{RFF}^T) )  ]  $

Naively this looks like the right notion to compute to know the empirical effectiveness of RFF in capturing the top-$k$ variance of a *given* dataset.  Have such estimates been done?

If $X$ is being sampled from some distribution $\cal{D}$ then maybe the more intrinsic thing to measure is, $\mathbb{E}_{X \sim \cal{D} }[\mathbb{E}_{\omega, \vec{b}}  [\sum_{i=1}^k ( \lambda_i (XX^T ) - \lambda_i (X_{RFF}X_{RFF}^T ) )  ] ]$

Comment: This seems more suitable for [stats.se].

Comment: Thanks! Can you maybe automatically cross-post it? (Or you can tell me how to do it!)

Comment: Cross-posting is forbidden, so don't post it in two places.  To migrate (move) it, click "flag" under the post and flag it for moderator attention and ask them to migrate it.  Or, just delete it here and post it there.

Comment: I have flagged it for moving.